# Issues with the Boolean Modifier on Blender 2.83

Tags: modifiers

I'm trying to make a window on a wall, and i choose the boolean mod, my window (cube) doesn't appear when i try to choose it in the Objects, to i use the copy tool next to where you choose the object, and i tap on my window cube, and it says "failed to set Value" The value is currently at Default (0.000001) any tips? Also I just stared Blender 2 days ago, so a bit of a Newbie, have been following video tutorials but none of them explain any issues like this.[image]

Comment: it might not appear because a boolean doesn't remove the boolean object, so the cube hides the hole, maybe try to apply the boolean and move the cube to see if the boolean works?

Answer (score 0):

It might just need to be applied, the changes you have done before using boolean. this sometimes makes it happy, some times not!! Command or control A Keys.

Comment: The problem is that the Boolean modifier cannot set the cube to act as a Boolean. Applying the modifier at this stage is the same as deleting it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the boolean modifier is in the wall and not the cube. If it is, apply it, and move the cube out of the way or delete it.